# MySQL incorrect Syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 20: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'now()' at line 1

Here is line 20:

```
ALTER TABLE item ALTER COLUMN release_date SET DEFAULT now();
```

Does anyone know the issue with this syntax?

Comment: running mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE item 
MODIFY COLUMN release_date datetime DEFAULT now();
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3c0fd/1)

Comment: Gave me the exact same error: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 20: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_timestamp' at line 1